# Recursively call array_values() to re-index variable depth menu array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, reindex

I have a multi-dimensional array and was able to successfully re-index the level keys (they were indexed at 1 and JSON was treating it like an object instead of an array) using `array_values()`.

However, I need the `subNavigationItems` subarrays to be re-indexed as well.

This is what I currently am receiving with `array_values($arr)`:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'navigationMenuId' => '1',
    'parentNavigationMenuId' => '0',
    'contentId' => '1',
    'fullURL' => '/index',
    'contentSlug' => 'index',
    'contentAlias' => 'Index',
    'navigationAnchor' => 'Home',
    'navigationOrder' => '1',
    'subNavigationItems' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'navigationMenuId' => '2',
    'parentNavigationMenuId' => '0',
    'contentId' => '15',
    'fullURL' => '/top-nav-1/index',
    'contentSlug' => 'index',
    'contentAlias' => 'Index',
    'navigationAnchor' => 'Top Nav 1',
    'navigationOrder' => '2',
    'subNavigationItems' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'navigationMenuId' => '3',
    'parentNavigationMenuId' => '0',
    'contentId' => '7',
    'fullURL' => '/top-nav-2/index',
    'contentSlug' => 'index',
    'contentAlias' => 'Index',
    'navigationAnchor' => 'Top Nav 2',
    'navigationOrder' => '3',
    'subNavigationItems' => 
    array (
      4 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '4',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '3',
        'contentId' => '8',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-2/sub-nav-1',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-1',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 1',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 1',
        'navigationOrder' => '1',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      5 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '5',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '3',
        'contentId' => '10',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-2/sub-nav-2',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-2',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 2',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 2',
        'navigationOrder' => '2',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      6 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '6',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '3',
        'contentId' => '9',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-2/sub-nav-3',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-3',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 3',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 3',
        'navigationOrder' => '3',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      7 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '7',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '3',
        'contentId' => '11',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-2/sub-nav-4',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-4',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 4',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 4',
        'navigationOrder' => '4',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'navigationMenuId' => '8',
    'parentNavigationMenuId' => '0',
    'contentId' => '5',
    'fullURL' => '/top-nav-3/index',
    'contentSlug' => 'index',
    'contentAlias' => 'Top Nav 3',
    'navigationAnchor' => 'Top Nav 3',
    'navigationOrder' => '4',
    'subNavigationItems' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'navigationMenuId' => '9',
    'parentNavigationMenuId' => '0',
    'contentId' => '6',
    'fullURL' => '/top-nav-4/index',
    'contentSlug' => 'index',
    'contentAlias' => 'Top Nav 4',
    'navigationAnchor' => 'Top Nav 4',
    'navigationOrder' => '5',
    'subNavigationItems' => 
    array (
      10 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '10',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '9',
        'contentId' => '12',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-4/sub-nav-1',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-1',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 1',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 1',
        'navigationOrder' => '1',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      11 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '11',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '9',
        'contentId' => '13',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-4/sub-nav-2',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-2',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 2',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 2',
        'navigationOrder' => '2',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      12 => 
      array (
        'navigationMenuId' => '12',
        'parentNavigationMenuId' => '9',
        'contentId' => '14',
        'fullURL' => '/top-nav-4/sub-nav-3',
        'contentSlug' => 'sub-nav-3',
        'contentAlias' => 'Sub Nav 3',
        'navigationAnchor' => 'Sub Nav 3',
        'navigationOrder' => '3',
        'subNavigationItems' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'navigationMenuId' => '13',
    'parentNavigationMenuId' => '0',
    'contentId' => '4',
    'fullURL' => '/top-nav-5/index',
    'contentSlug' => 'index',
    'contentAlias' => 'Top Nav 5',
    'navigationAnchor' => 'Top Nav 5',
    'navigationOrder' => '6',
    'subNavigationItems' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)
```

Notice how the first nested array indexes are 4, 5, 6, and 7, and the indexes of the second one are 10, 11, and 12.  I need them both to start at 0.  It would also be great if the function to do this can be an infinitely-recursive function.

If you see every single item has a `subNavigationItems` array that could potentially be filled with more things and I would need those arrays to be re-indexed at 0 as well.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
<?php 

    function reOrderArray($array) {
        if(! is_array($array)) {
             return $array;
        }
        $count = 0;
        $result = array();
        foreach($array as $k => $v) {
            if(is_integer_value($k)) {
               $result[$count] = reOrderArray($v);
               ++$count;
            } else {
              $result[$k] = reOrderArray($v);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function is_integer_value($value) {
        if(!is_int($value)) {
            if(is_string($value) && preg_match("/^-?\d+$/i",$value)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
function reindex_array_recursive($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (array_keys($array) === range(0, count($array) - 1)) { // Indexed array
            return array_values(array_map('reindex_array_recursive', $array));
        } else { // Associative array
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $value = reindex_array_recursively($value);
            }
            return $array;
        }
    } else {
        return $array;
    }
}
```

It doesn't recurse into objects, only sub-arrays.

Answer (score -1):

The child arrays are predictably placed in the `subNavigationItems` keyed elements, so it is unnecessary to check the data type of every element in every level.

The recursive call of `array_values()` to re-index keys only needs to be called upon on `subNavigationItems` and only if it is not empty.

The following is noticeably much cleaner and has less functional overhead than the other answers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hoiX0))

```
function reindexChildren(array $array): array {
    foreach ($array as &$item) {
        if ($item['subNavigationItems']) {
            $item = reindexChildren($item['subNavigationItems']);
        }
    }
    return array_values($array);
}

var_export(
    reindexChildren($menu)
);
```

Comment: Dear Stack Overflow, are we still DV'ing answers that are correct, explained, demonstrated, and use best practice?  We wouldn't want researchers to find an optimized answer, would we?  Better skew the public perception so that Stack Overflow is not a reputable tool for researchers.